# How to stay for each id in Data Frame only rows for one random month from column with dates in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'day': ['2023-03-01', '2023-03-10', '2023-04-05', '2023-03-15', '2023-04-20', '2023-04-25'],
                   'col1' : [123, 66, 7, 890, 456, 100]})
```

[image]

And for each id I need to stay only rows for random one month. For example for cont_id = 1 I need to stay only rows for march (03 month) or only rows for april (04 month).

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
id   | day        | col1
-----|------------|-------
1    | 2023-03-01 | 123
1    | 2023-03-10 | 66
2    | 2023-04-20 | 456
2    | 2023-04-25 | 100
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) to get a random day, then convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), then compare each row with the mapped values as period to perform [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# ensure datetime
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])

# select random day per group, convert to period
keep = df.groupby('id').sample(1).set_index('id')['day'].dt.to_period('M')

# keep days of the same period for each group
out = df[df['id'].map(keep).eq(df['day'].dt.to_period('M'))]
```

Example output:

```
   id        day  col1
0   1 2023-03-01   123
1   1 2023-03-10    66
4   2 2023-04-20   456
5   2 2023-04-25   100
```

##### Keeping the dates as object

You have 2 options

Simply use a temporary series to perform the date operations

```
# ensure datetime
tmp = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])

# select random day per group, convert to period
keep = df.assign(tmp=tmp).groupby('id').sample(1).set_index('id')['tmp'].dt.to_period('M')

# keep days of the same period for each group
out = df[df['id'].map(keep).eq(tmp.dt.to_period('M'))]
```

Or slice the string to keep only the YYYY-MM part

```
# keep only YYYY-MM
tmp = df['day'].str[:7]

# select random YYYY-MM per group
keep = df.assign(tmp=tmp).groupby('id').sample(1).set_index('id')['tmp']

# keep days of the same YYYY-MM
out = df[df['id'].map(keep).eq(tmp)]
```

##### How it works:

```
# select one period per ID
# keep = df.groupby('id').sample(1).set_index('id')['day'].dt.to_period('M')

id
1    2023-03
2    2023-04
Name: day, dtype: period[M]

# check if the current day's period is the same as the chosen reference
# df['id'].map(keep).eq(df['day'].dt.to_period('M'))

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: mozway, what if my day column with dates is an object type and I can not change type of this column to datetime like in your code (df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])) because previously I made some transformation and this columns have to stay as object? Could you modify your code? It works great but it has to work bo object column "day"

Comment: @dingaro you can always convert back to object afterwards, but another easy option is to use a temporary series for the operation. See update.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function with [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html), compare by months periods ([`Serie.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['day']).dt.to_period('M')

df = df[s.eq(s.groupby(df['id']).transform(lambda x: x.sample(1).iat[0]))]
print (df)
   id        day  col1
0   1 2023-03-01   123
1   1 2023-03-10    66
4   2 2023-04-20   456
5   2 2023-04-25   100
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['day']).dt.to_period('M'))
0    2023-03
1    2023-03
2    2023-04
3    2023-03
4    2023-04
5    2023-04
Name: day, dtype: period[M]

print (s.groupby(df['id']).transform(lambda x: x.sample(1).iat[0]))
0    2023-03
1    2023-03
2    2023-03
3    2023-04
4    2023-04
5    2023-04
Name: day, dtype: period[M]

print (s.eq(s.groupby(df['id']).transform(lambda x: x.sample(1).iat[0])))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: day, dtype: bool
```

Comment: jezrael, what if my day column with dates is an object type and I can not change type of this column to datetime like in your code (df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])) because previously I made some transformation and this columns have to stay as object? Could you modify your code? It works great but it has to work bo object column "day"

Comment: @dingaro - Solution was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) with `group_keys=False` to apply a function that selects one random month.

```
import random
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'])

# Function to filter rows for a random month for each id
def filter_random_month(group):
    random_month = random.choice(group['day'].dt.month.unique())
    return group[group['day'].dt.month == random_month]

# Apply the filtering function to each group of rows based on 'id'
filtered_df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(filter_random_month)

print(filtered_df)
```

Comment: Assuming OP wants a monthly period, using `.dt.month` wouldn't work if you have several years with the same month, that would pick `2023-03-01` and `2022-03-10` (OP should clarify in this case)